# How do I use Pyinstaller to make a Mac file on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am on Windows and I am trying to figure how to use Pyinstaller to make a file (on Windows) for a Mac.

I have no trouble with Windows I am just not sure how I would make a file for another OS on it.

What I tried in cmd was: pyinstaller -F myfile.py and I am not sure what to change to make a Mac compatible file.

Comment: This is not possible, have a look at the [pyinstaller FAQ](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ#features).

Comment: Oh okay, is there anything else you know of that I could use to do this?

Comment: There is no way to do that, review this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772216/how-to-create-os-x-app-with-python-on-windows). The closest thing is [nuitka](http://nuitka.net/), but i didnt try to cross compile. Or install OSX in virtualbox and use pyinstaller there.

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible without using a Virtual Machine