# Is it possible to write a python script on Mac OS x for use on Windows as executable

Tags: python, macos, exe, py2exe, py2app

I am writing a python script on Mac and want my windows user to be able to run it in their computer without having to install all the packages. Is this possible? 
I´ve found a lot of ways to make executables for the platform it was developed on but not for cross-platform.

Comment: py2exe is only for use on windows

Comment: One way is to create a Windows virtual machine on the Mac using something like VirtualBox and compile/build on that.  But really if you have Windows users you should have a Windows machine.

Comment: Thats my conclusion too. I´ve got an windows computer I can use, but was hoping I didn't have to

Comment: Even if you used Nuitka and found a cross-compiler, the modules would be an issue.   Also checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency/18693145#18693145 especially my answer :-)  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248989/clang-c-cross-compiler-generating-windows-executable-from-mac-os-x