# How/can/Is it possible to run/open/link/develop a DirectX project using CLion?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, clion

I've recently installed CLion in the hopes that I can start using this over visual studios and it seems to be decent for at least regular c++ projects etc but I am wondering how and if I can use it to develop directx code. In visual studios you simply have the directx folder along side your project like so

C:/myproject/main.cpp

C:/DirectXTK/directxfiles etc

and you can import and link the files by either dragging them onto the project or using the import files and it will link them up etc is there anyway I can do this using CLion? for a fairly new programmer it's super confusing. I tried googling adding libraries and such but I struggled to understand most of what exactly was said, could someone explain it to me please? and if you can will it run just as it would run in visual studio?(and would it run on a mac)

My reason for wanting to use CLion is simply because I'd like to be able to run CLion on my mac and be able to run and test without having to use my current solution which is parallels/bootcamp/running windows then visual studios etc. Unless someone has a better idea?

Thanks in advance if someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no DirectX on Mac OS X, OS X uses OpenGL instead.

So using CLion would not solve your problem.

Comment: I know that much but I figured if I have all the sdk files with it etc then it'd work? Considering its already in a compiler running c++ on osx?

Comment: Well then you still have to crosscompile. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248989/clang-c-cross-compiler-generating-windows-executable-from-mac-os-x for some details