# Mac - c++ - create file.exe

Tags: c++, xcode, eclipse, macos, executable

I've write a c++ project using xcode on a mac.

What I need is to create a .exe file to run the project on windows in anothre pc (no virtualization).

I've read that xcode doesn't provide this service and so I've tried to compile it also in Eclipse (on mac) but I'm not able to get the .exe file.

Is it possible, on mac, to generate a .exe of a c++ project runnable on windows?

Thank you

Comment: At least not that easily. You could try running some C++ compiler (for Windows! maybe MinGW or fully featured Visual Studio's compiler) in Wine or a virtual machine. I personally had some success with both methods and have always been compiling [my project](http://brute.zohosites.com) like this.

Comment: Looks like this question may be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248989/clang-c-cross-compiler-generating-windows-executable-from-mac-os-x

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible and it's known as cross-compilation. Besides building your own toolchain for doing this, you can use MinGW: Cross compiling with MinGW

Comment: MinGW on a Mac? Really?

Comment: Consider using MinGW on Mac OS X to compile Windows binaries. Here are instructions on how to do it on Linux: http://www.blogcompiler.com/2010/07/11/compile-for-windows-on-linux/

You'll have to adapt them for Mac OS X and you may have to compile MinGW yourself.

http://www.mingw.org

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!!!

Comment: Glad I helped !