# How to get .exe output from qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

In Qt-Creator, mac, i'm using a sample project from Qt-Creator and now i want to get .exe output of this project and run it on any Windows computer.

Comment: If you want to generate an executable for windows you must compile it in windows or do a crosscompiler (this second option can be complicated)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clang C++ Cross Compiler - Generating Windows Executable from Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248989/clang-c-cross-compiler-generating-windows-executable-from-mac-os-x)